# How to start Postgres service via pg_ctl in Ansible in background?

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.11.0 and PostgreSQL 13

I'm using the PostgreSQL binaries to start the PostgreSQL service in Ansible, like this

```
- name: "Start PostgreSQL version {{ pg_version }} service"
  win_shell: "pg_ctl.exe -D {{ pg_data_dir }} -l {{ pg_log_file }} start"
```

and the service does start. However, the playbook is stuck at that task, and doesn't proceed with subsequent tasks, presumably because it mimics entering that command in Powershell, where the command doesn't come back.

How can I perform the `pg_ctl start` command in the "background" so the task proceeds? Note, per docs, the `-W` (don't wait for start/stop to complete) is the default option so I shouldn't have to add it. But even if I do, the task doesn't proceed.

Comment: Surely the answer is to use [`win_service:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/windows/win_service_module.html) for that, right? But if you insist, I would guess [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Start-Job?view=powershell-7.1) is the PS equivalent of doing `pg_ctl ... &` in bash

Comment: @mdaniel, what a smart idea! I'll try `win_services`. thanks!

Comment: `win_service` does start the service, but it doesn't take arguments, so I couldn't pass it a log file like in my command. I did `pg_ctl register ...` task before I ran the `win_service` task, which had the `-l logname` option, but that doesn't start the logs in that file.

Comment: I couldn't make sense of `Start-Job` LOL! (Linux person here.)

Comment: @mdaniel did you mean `Start-Job -ScriptBlock { pg_ctl ...}`?